# How can I use scriptable objects for upgrade card system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scriptable-object

I have a question about scriptable objects. I know that making changes on scriptable objects during run time permanently affects its values.

For my use case, I'm trying to create a game (similar to slay the spire) and created a Card scriptable object.

How can I create an upgrade system for the cards that don't modify the original scriptable objects variables (e.g., card attack)?

Comment: It’s not entirely clear what you are trying to do other than you want to modify something at runtime.  Please explain in detail but without mentioning scriptable objects as I think thats an XY Problem.

Comment: What are "scriptable objects" (in this context)? Is it a concept in Unity? Or is it the literal class "ScriptableObject" (instances of that class)?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you shouldn't change ScriptableObject values at runtime. You can create a copy of it and then edit them freely.

You can think about List with ScriptableObjects for each upgrade: NormalSoldier_Tier1, NormalSoldier_Tier2...